# Save attachments to a new Windows folder?

Tags: vba, outlook

Every time I receive an email with the subject "Test", I want to:

1. Automatically extract all attachments and store them in its own new created folder.
2. Automatically copy the email inside this new folder
3. Automatically add a Word document inside this new folder.
4. The folder must be named by the date received.

The code I have copies all attachments in a pre-selected folder, but it doesn't create a personal folder for them.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Only act if it's a MailItem
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
        Set Msg = item

    'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
        If (Msg.Subject = "Heures") And _
        (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

    'Set folder to save in.
    Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim Att As Variant

    Const attPath As String = "C:\Users\NASC02\Test\"

    ' save attachment
    Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
    For Each Att In myAttachments
    Att.SaveAsFile attPath & Att.FileName

Next

    ' mark as read
   Msg.UnRead = False



End If
End If


ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: Your original post was too broad. It could have been closed. Ask only one question at a time, as is **expected** on this Q & A (not a forum). Now you have negated the answer provided and not awarded the fake internet points, if you had accepted the answer.  Fake internet points encourage responses. You can roll back this post and ask a new question about creating a folder.

Comment: @niton thank your for your comment. You are absolutely right. I'm new to this website and i'm trying to be in the guidelines as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att
```

needs to be changed to

```
Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
for each Att in myAttachments 
    Att.SaveAsFile attPath & Att.FileName
next
```

Comment: It does'nt work. It gives me an error compilation '' for each must be variable or object ''

Comment: nvm, it worked, but that's only one part of the problem!

Comment: for anyone who is interested in how i made it work, i just had to add `Dim Att As Variant`